# How to remove parent tag with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to remove the header cells from a html table using BeautifulSoup. I have something like;

```
<tr> <th> head1 </th> <th> head2 </th> </tr>
```

I am using the following code to remove all the header cells;

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(url)    
for headless in soup.find_all('th'):
        headless.decompose()
```

This works great, except I am left with an empty row which messes things up later;

```
<tr> </tr>
```

I tried the following code but I get an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decompose'

```
for headless in soup.find_all('th'):
    headless.parent.decompose()
```

How can I either get rid of the row containing header cells or remove the blank row later? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you removed the outer `<tr>` at the first iteration (when `headless=<th>head2</th>`), so that when the iteration reaches `<th>head2</th>` it's parent is `None`.

You could, instead, iterate through `<tr>`s having child `<td>` like so :

```
for headless in (tr for tr in soup.find_all('tr') if tr.find('th')):
    headless.decompose()
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked beautifully. I was also able to get rid a blank table that had a form I removed in it.

Comment: Actually the page was a lot messier than I thought. For some of the data, there is a row (1) that contains a table, and inside the table are two rows, one header row (2) and one data row(3). When I used your suggestion, it erased the top row(1), which also got rid of my data row(3).  Something like this: <tr><table><tr><th>headers...</th></tr><tr><td>data...</td></tr></table></tr>. Any ideas on how to erase the immediate header row while keeping the data row?